# Mongoid cache not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, mongoid

I tried to cache my mongoid query,

But it seems it still takes me long time to fetch data from database

And how to expire with time it if it works. For example I wanna expire the cache every 1 hour.

## log from console

```
  MOPED: localhost:12345 QUERY        database=lazy_bird collection=ana selector={"$query"=>{"from"=>/.*TPE.*/, "to"=>/.*KIX|OSA.*/flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil runtime: 15690.6070ms
```

## Query

```
# modelize(route[:airline]) will give me a model
Model.recent_month(route[:from], route[:to]).cache.to_a

scope :recent_month, ->(from, to) {
  where(from: /.*#{from}.*/, to: /.*#{to}.*/ ).without(:history).order_by(flight_date: 1)
}
```